# Fluid HTML email template

Tags: html, email

I created this as a template for our email marketing team to use when creating emails. For fluid/responsive behavior, I am using max-width and conditionals for clients that do not support it (e.g., Microsoft Outlook).

If anyone could give some suggestions for improvement, that would be appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TITLE HERE</title>
<!-- fix for 1px offset in <ol> & <ul> tags in MSO 7-13 - NEEDS TO BE IN <head> tag-->
<!--[if mso | ie]>
<style>
li {
    text-indent: -1em; /* Normalise space between bullets and text */
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color:#767575;">
<!--640px wrapper to match <table>--> 
<!--[if mso | ie]>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:640px;" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<![endif]-->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:100%; max-width:640px;">
    <tr>

  <td align="center"><!--View on web-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%; padding:20px; font-family: Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:12px; color:#333333; font-weight:normal;" align="center"> To view this email as a web page, click <a href="%%view_email_url%%" style="color:#0891CC;">here</a>. </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End view on web--> 
    <!--Track Label-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#989898; width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%; padding:20px; font-family: Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:20px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:normal;"> SUBJECT LINE HERE </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End Track Label--> 
    <!--Track Intro-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:20px; background-color:#133055;; width:100%;">
      <tr valign="top" align="center">
        <td style="display:inline-block; width: 135px; line-height:0px;"><table>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="https://assets.livehealthier.com/shared/img/placeholder_135.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; height:auto; line-height:0px;"/></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>

        <!--420px wrapper to match <td>--> 
        <!--[if mso | ie]>
            <td style="width:420px !important;">
            <![endif]-->
        <td style="display:inline-block; max-width:420px; padding:20px; vertical-align:top;"><h1 style="margin:0px 0px 16px 0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:36px; line-height:40px; color:#ffffff; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</h1>
          <p style="margin:0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#ffffff; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.</p></td>
        <!--END 420px wrapper--> 
        <!--[if mso | ie]>
            </td>
            <![endif]--> 

      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End Track Intro--> 
    <!--Goals-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; background-color:#676767;">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td style="padding: 20px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; color:#ffffff; text-align:left; height:auto;"><strong>INCENTIVE TEXT HERE</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; max-width: 320px;"><!--[if mso | ie]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://client.livehealthier.com/V2/Memberservices/ontrack/index.aspx" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:320px;" arcsize="15%" strokecolor="#0891CC" fillcolor="#0891CC">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">ACTION HERE</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--> 
          <!–[if !mso]> 
          <a href="https://client.livehealthier.com/V2/Memberservices/ontrack/index.aspx" style="background-color:#0891CC;border:1px solid #0891CC;border-radius:15px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:320px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">ACTION HERE</a> 
          <![endif]--></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End Goals--> 

    <!--***MAIN CONTENT***--> 

    <!--Section -->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%; padding:20px 20px 0px 20px"><h2 style="font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:24px; font-weight: normal; color:#133055;">A un Angleso it va semblar un simplificat Angles</h2>
          <p style="margin:0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#333333; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End Section --> 

    <!--Section -->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:30px 0px 0px 20px; width:100%;">
      <tr valign="top" align="center">
        <td style="display:inline-block; line-height:0px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 135px;" bgcolor="#133055"><img src="https://assets.livehealthier.com/shared/img/placeholder_135.jpg" alt="" style="width:135px; height:auto; line-height:0px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 20px;"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>

        <!--450px wrapper to match <td>--> 
        <!--[if mso | ie]>
         <td style="width: 450px !important;">
         <![endif]-->
        <td style="display:inline-block; max-width:450px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px; vertical-align:top;"><h2 style="margin:0px 0px 16px 0px;font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:24px; line-height:28px; font-weight: normal; color:#133055; text-align:left;">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</h2>
          <ol style="Margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 20px">
            <li style="Margin:0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#133055; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;"><span style="color:#333333;">Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues.</span></li>
            <li style="Margin:0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#133055; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;"><span style="color:#333333;">Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues.</span></li>
            <li style="Margin:0px; font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#133055; text-align:left; font-weight:normal;"><span style="color:#333333;">It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental: in fact, it va esser Occidental.</span></li>
          </ol></td>

        <!--END 450px wrapper--> 
        <!--[if mso | ie]>
             </td>
             <![endif]--> 

      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--End Section --> 

    <!--***END MAIN CONTENT***--> 

    <!--Footer-->

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:20px;"><hr></td>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><img src="https://assets.livehealthier.com/shared/img/placeholder_320.jpg" alt="" title=""><br>
          <br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; margin:0px;"><p style="font-family:Arial, 'san-serif'; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
            <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"> <br>
              <br>
              This email was sent by: <strong>%%Member_Busname%%</strong><br>
              %%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%%<br>
              <br>
              We respect your right to privacy <a href="http://email.exacttarget.com/Company/Policies/PrivacyPolicy.html?linkid=View+Privacy+Policy" style="color: #0891CC;">view our policy.</a><br>
              <a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" style="color: #0891CC;">Manage Subscriptions</a> | <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" style="color: #0891CC;">Update Profile</a> | <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" style="color: #0891CC;">Unsubscribe</a><br>
              <br>
              </custom>
            <br>
            <br>
          </p></td>
      </tr>
        </tr>

    </table></td>
    </tr>


  <!--End Footer-->

</table>
<!--End 640px wrapper to match <table>--> 
<!--[if mso | ie]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```